# how to make interpret date as 3 12 not 31 2 in ddmmyyyy format

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, strftime

my date format come in format `11122020`  (ddmmyyyy)  in a pandas column.

I use

```
datapdf["wholetime"]=pd.to_datetime(datapdf["wholetime"],format='%d%m%Y)
```

to convert to time and do processing on the time.

recently my code failed for date 3122020   as

```
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

python is interpreting as 31 2 2020  instead of 3 12 2020 which is causing the error.  Any one have solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be to use `str.zfill` to ensure that date is in 8 digits:

```
s = pd.Series(["11122020", "3122020"])
pd.to_datetime(s.str.zfill(8), format="%d%m%Y")
```

Output:

```
0   2020-12-11
1   2020-12-03
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Note that this answer only concerns about missing 0 in the day. It won't be able to parse more ambiguous items such as `332020`, where the *month* part also requires heading 0.

Comment: Now this would have problem with `'572020'`, upvoted regardless. Modification would be easy enough. On the other hand, that would/should not be a concern, otherwise `1112020` would be ambiguous.

Comment: @QuangHoang True. I will add a note

Comment: '572020' was my concern too..  luckily they are sending month with zero padding.   zfill perfectly helps my case.. Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

Little bit newbie approach using `apply` I created custom parser for dates, if you have some other formats in it then you can tweak the function w.r.t your date formats,

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    #assuming your dates are mix of ddmmyyyy,dmmyyyy,dmyyyy
    'date': ['11122020','3122020','572020','','222019','3112019']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def parser(elem):
  res = ''
  if len(elem) > 7:
    res = elem
  elif len(elem) > 6:
    d = '0' + elem[0]
    m = elem[1:3]
    y = elem[3:]
    res = d+m+y
  elif len(elem) > 5:
    d = '0' + elem[0]
    m = '0' + elem[1]
    y = elem[2:]
    res = d+m+y
  else:
    res = ''


  return pd.to_datetime(res, format='%d%m%Y',errors='coerce')

df['date'] = df['date'].apply(parser)
df
```

output:

```
    date
0   2020-12-11
1   2020-12-03
2   2020-07-05
3   NaT
4   2019-02-02
5   2019-11-03
```